# Fixing Subversion Repository

Tags: svn, netbeans

This is a very annoying problem with Subversion.  The problem is talked about in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136044/cant-open-svn-text-base-file-svn-base), but I don't see how to apply the solution to my situation.

I am developing using Netbeans 7-beta and sometimes use my Mac, sometimes my Windows system, and I made the mistake of renaming a file (using Netbeans refactoring) where the rename was just changing the case of the letters.   Then there were subsequent checkins from both the Mac and the Windows side -- I don't remember exactly what step did the damage.

The result is that if I try to just go to check out the project on any system, I get the error:

```
svn: Can't open file zzzzz/.svn/tmp/text-base/xxxxx.java.svn-base
```

where the tokens zzzzz and xxxxx are specific to my project.   The xxxxx was once named xXxXx or something.

I can check out the plain code (no .svn directories) and create a new repository, but that will lose all my history.  Trying to get Netbeans to check in the file with the original name doesn't seem to work either.   Is there another way to clean this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136044/cant-open-svn-text-base-file-svn-base/2455082#2455082) in the [thread you referred to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136044/cant-open-svn-text-base-file-svn-base) I would suggest inspecting the files in the folder using TortoiseSVN's repo browser - it appears likely that you'll find two files with the same name but different case.  *From within repo browser* delete one of the files, and try your update again.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Tortoise product, but I'll download it and give it a try.  Are the operations you are referring to perform operations directly on the repository or on the working copy?

Comment: Anything you do in TortoiseSVN's repo browser is done directly on the repository - good question.  After you use repo browser to modify your repository, you'll have to do an update on your working copy to get the changes.  Btw, TortoiseSVN is great - it's a huge help.  It allows you to do all of your SVN operations from within Windows Explorer, and has a ton of nice graphical interfaces and tools.

Comment: OK, I went and did this and it works.  A few caveats for the the benefit of anyone else with this problem:  1) TortoiseSVN is a Windows program, and I am working on a Mac.  Fortunately I had a Windows XP Virtual Machine to work from.  2) I had to use Cygwin's ssh client to connect to my repository -- for some reason I couldn't get PLINK.EXE or TortoiseSVN's version of it to work.   3) The repository browser is sort of hidden -- you can get to it by opening a file explorer window, right clicking, and follow the sub-menu.