# Error: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm just working as normal. Suddenly my commit gets this error:

```
Commit failed (details follow):
Can't open file
'C:\\...\\map\\.svn\text-base\\addressMatcher.php.svn-base':
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have done nothing fishy with my subversion folders, and cleanup doesn't help.

How do I fix this / What do I do?

---

Edit: I just snooped in the SVN folder and noticed that the aforementioned file is called "`addressmatcher.php3.svn-base`" for some reason.
I smell failed renaming operations by Eclipse.
Renaming the file to the correct filename gives a checksum error, so I undid the operation.
Any advice on how I might fix this without having to perform a clean checkout and patching everything over?

Comment: The "map.svn" bit looks fishy; shouldn't that be "map\.svn"?  I don't know why it would be happening, but it's a clue to look into anyway.

Comment: It's just stackoverflow assuming the backslashes are escapes. I fixed it (And updated my question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you saw, this is a case issue (detailed in SO question "[Can't open .svn/text-base/file.svn-base ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136044/cant-open-svn-text-base-file-svn-base/2455082#2455082)")

One comment suggests:

> It happened to me in a subfolder within a much more massive folder.
>   Instead of wiping out my entire project, I was able to "fix" it by deleting the subfolder from the commandline, and then doing a `svn update`, which restored the missing subfolder.

Answer (score 12):

Hi i meet similar problem today.

```
cannot find the file \.svn\pristine\24\24fd530d4bd82341fb514ab912c9e10adbc4ad89.svn-base
```

And i use the simple way to fix this problem.

i look up this file did not exist under that folder.so i just copy a svn-base from other file and rename this with 24fd530d4bd82341fb514ab912c9e10adbc4ad89.svn-base.And then do the clean up operation.
After that i meet another file missing.using the same way and at last i fix this problem.
Hope it can help you

in other words the solution is
    copy a svn-base file and  rename with the missing files name.

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect the project [Team->Disconnect], and choose to delete svn metadata.

Then reconnect [Team->Share project] the project, choosing the right folder in the repository. 
Eclipse will checkout (download) the HEAD revision and everything will be repaired.

*WARNING*,  this may (& probably will) delete anything you did between now and the last commit. I suggest hard copying your changed sources if in doubt.

Comment: hanks @polvoazul, this exactly the solution ...but it doesn't delete the current work in eclipse ...