# Svn checkout/update/cleanup fails. Looking for a temp file to copy

Tags: svn

I've got problem with subversion. I already lost my changes so I'm open for any solutions.
When I checkout a certain repository I get the following error:

'D:\test.svn\pristine\ac\acb7917332370248f3b347431657f5146537225d.svn-base':
 The system cannot find the file specified.
Additional errors:
Can't create directory 'D:\test.svn\pristine\ac': Cannot create a file when
 that file already exists.

This is completely fresh checkout from the repo. The remote is working ok.(other programmers can access the remote without problems). We are working on 2 repos for different kind of files and the second repository is working fine for me.

After searching the web this is the closest error message I could find on the web:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/subversion_users/gY6mEqWnqiM

I'm using tortoise SVN 1.8.0. If you have any questions to ask, do it.

P.S. It worked. Everything except the deleted folder got downloaded. However it says: "Skipped, remains conflicted.". How should I get that folder?

P.S.2 Yeap but the file which is causing the problem is still causing it. I cannot work with that folder. The solution just helped me to update the other files. The problematic file is called "lua5.2.lua" and is in dir named "tools".

P.S.3 To the first comment below: I tried upgrading to 1.8.1 and downlgrading to 1.7.x. Didn't work either of these.

Comment: Upgrade to TortoiseSVN 1.8.1. There were a number of important fixes made in this release. It may not solve the current problem but it's always wise to keep up with bug fixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem long after I posted the question.

Avast antivirus was thinking of some .svn files as malicios and was silently removing them. Disabling the antivirus solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was suggested here: [Can't open .svn/text-base/file.svn-base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136044/cant-open-svn-text-base-file-svn-base/2455082#2455082)

> It happened to me in a subfolder within a much more massive folder.
>   Instead of wiping out my entire project, I was able to "fix" it by deleting the subfolder from the commandline, and then doing a svn update, which restored the missing  subfolder.

Comment: Yep. This is the only thing I didn't try. ;d Lost some days.. Nevermind, something different is happening. I'll be back with the results soon.